# How to get event when grid's roweditor moves

Tags: javascript, extjs, ext4

I have grid and rowediting plugin... So I need to fetch record that was firstly edited, when plugin is enabled and shown and other record in grid clicked to edit...
Maybe some 'oneditchange' event but I see nothing like this exists in docs. Or simply prevent edition this clicktomoveedit possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent selecting others grid records during edition of new, this can help

```
    enableEditingProtection: true,
    skippingEditingProtection: false,

    editingPhantomRecord: false,

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.on('beforeedit', me.onBeforeEdit);
        me.on('beforeselect', me.onBeforeSelect);

        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    skipEditingProtection: function() {
        this.skippingEditingProtection = true;
    },

    onBeforeEdit: function(editor, context) {
        if (this.enableEditingProtection &&
            !this.skippingEditingProtection &&
            editor.editing &&
            this.editingPhantomRecord
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        this.getSelectionModel().select(context.record);
        this.editingPhantomRecord = context.record.phantom;
        this.skippingEditingProtection = false;

        return true;
    },

    onBeforeSelect: function() {
        return !this.enableEditingProtection ||
            !this.getPlugin('row-editor') ||
            !(this.getPlugin('row-editor').editing && this.editingPhantomRecord);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit( editor, e, eOpts )**
Fires after a cell is edited. Usage example:

```
grid.on('edit', function(editor, e) {

    e.record.commit();
     console.log(e.value);  // the value you want
});
```

**Parameters**

editor : Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

e : Object
An edit event with the following properties:

grid - The grid
record - The record that was edited

field - The field name that was edited

value - The value being set     **// the value you want**

originalValue - The original value for the field, before the edit.

row - The grid table row

column - The grid Column defining the column that was edited.

rowIdx - The row index that was edited

colIdx - The column index that was edited

eOpts : Object

The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.

Overrides: Ext.grid.plugin.Editing.edit